# Controller definition inside Angular's ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an Angular 1.3 application using ngRoute module. I'd like to be able to define a controller in the same file as the view, but for some reasons, Angular does not recognize it:

**view.html:**

```
<script>
  angular.module("app").controller("fooController", function() {});
</script>
<div ng-controller="fooController"></div>
```

**module.js:**

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
// ...
```

**index.html:**

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="module.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```

The above setup throws an error: Argument 'fooController' is not a function, got undefined.

Tt worked before 1.3, when controllers could be defined as global functions. **Also, the problem does not appear when `$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();` is called during module configuration and controllers are defined as global functions.**

I know it's not the best idea to define a controller in the HTML file, but in this case I have a good reason for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's the plunker showing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/JU350xL7X9ryF3S72o6s

Click on the link there to change the route and take a look at the browser's console.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps you need to have the `ng-view` after the scripts since in the `view.html` the global object `angular` hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: It's loaded for sure. Otherwise there would be an error saying it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue on Github for this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11384. Turns out this scenario is not supported (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the controller is yet to be instantiated when you/Angular are first attempting to use it.

My guess is that you are referencing the controller in the ngRoute definitions, and the ngRoute module is trying to cover the controller dependency before displaying your view.

If you were to update your question to include the route configurations, that might be more obvious.  A working (or non-working) Plnkr.co demo would be even better.

Comment: Sure, I've added an example on plunker. I'm not referencing the controller  inside the module config function, so in theory this should work...